# Wireless internet connection connects but internet does not work (no packets received). Wired does

Tags: windows-xp, wireless-networking

When I connect my PC via ethernet cable to my ADSL router it works fine. When I connect via Wireless it connects and the internet will work for a random amount of time and then stop working. It stays connected with a strong signal but no packets are received. My laptop/iphone are right next to it and wireless works fine.

If I open the Wireless USB status, it says it is connected to my SSID with full strength (54 mps - I am 3 meteres away from my router) and the activty shows as Packets 594 SENT and 105 RECEIVED (this goes up VERY slowly)

I have tried the following:

1. Turned off anitvirus and firewall completely.
2. Tested the wifi signal- I am writing this on my laptop which is next to my PC and also has full wifi strength.
3. Tried a different wireless adapter - I dug out an old PCI wireless card - it does the exact same thing.
4. Compared all wireless settings to my laptop.
5. I can ping google.com and it replies (sometimes with packet loss)
6. When I reboot the PC it will connect for a  minute or two (random time) and then just stops again.
7. I tried Firefox, IE  etc. no joy
8. I have updated all latest versions (Netgear WG111v2) and drivers
9. Checked Event Log - nothing unusual
10. Ping the router (and even connect
     as admin for the few minutes when
     the internet does work)
11. [Changed the MTU down to 1200 using
     DrTCP](http://kb.netgear.com/app/answers/detail/a_id/1153)
12. Checked Device Manager for
     conflicts - none.
13. I ping the router from the PC
     (192.168.0.10 -> 192.168.0.1) and
     it replies with 4 packets. BUT, on
     my router admin page (which I
     access via http on my laptop
     wirelessly) - if I ping
     192.168.0.10 all packets timeout (pinging my laptop 192.168.0.12
     works fine)
14. My router admin page shows the
     leased IP address for 192.168.0.10
     (ie it is definitely talking to the
     router initially)

Now I am out of ideas - please help. I think it is an OS/Software issue as I have tried 2 different wireless adapaters (PCI and USB) with the same result but all other wireless devices work fine around mine). It's not the firewall.

It is getting assigned an IP address correctly (my PC gets 192.168.0.10, my laptop is .12) It is assigned by DHCP.

As soon as I plug in the ethernet cable it all works fine. Repairing the adapter sometimes helps but it will always stop working after a random time. The wireless adapter always shows as connected with Excellent signal but the internet does not work.

I am running Windows XP SP3 and have tried a Netgear WG111v2 USB adapter.

Thanks in advance!

UPDATE:
The internet seems to be working, it is just either sending packets too small or slow to work (some small pages load bits of them very slowly but then hang).

XP seems to have a networking diagnostic app - here is the output:

```
Last diagnostic run time: 08/30/10 08:16:38 IP Configuration Diagnostic
Invalid IP address
info    Valid IP address detected: 192.168.0.10
IP Layer Diagnostic
Corrupted IP routing table
info    The default route is valid
info    The loopback route is valid
info    The local host route is valid
info    The local subnet route is valid
Invalid ARP cache entries
action  The ARP cache has been flushed
Gateway Diagnostic
Gateway
info    The following proxy configuration is being used by IE: Automatically Detect Settings:Disabled Automatic Configuration Script: Proxy Server: Proxy Bypass list:
info    This computer has the following default gateway entry(ies): 192.168.0.1
info    This computer has the following IP address(es): 192.168.0.10
info    The default gateway is in the same subnet as this computer
info    The default gateway entry is a valid unicast address
info    The default gateway address was resolved via ARP in 1 try(ies)
info    The default gateway was reached via ICMP Ping in 1 try(ies)
info    TCP port 80 on host 65.55.12.249 was successfully reached
info    The Internet host www.microsoft.com was successfully reached
info    The default gateway is OK
DNS Client Diagnostic
DNS - Not a home user scenario
info    Using Web Proxy: no
info    Resolving name ok for (www.microsoft.com): yes
No DNS servers
DNS failure
HTTP, HTTPS, FTP Diagnostic
HTTP, HTTPS, FTP connectivity
info    FTP (Passive): Successfully connected to ftp.microsoft.com.
info    HTTP: Successfully connected to www.microsoft.com.
warn    HTTPS: Error 12002 connecting to www.microsoft.com: The operation timed out
warn    HTTPS: Error 12002 connecting to www.passport.net: The operation timed out
error   Could not make an HTTPS connection.
info    Redirecting user to support call
WinSock Diagnostic
WinSock status
info    All base service provider entries are present in the Winsock catalog.
info    The Winsock Service provider chains are valid.
info    Provider entry MSAFD Tcpip [TCP/IP] passed the loopback communication test.
info    Provider entry MSAFD Tcpip [UDP/IP] passed the loopback communication test.
info    Provider entry RSVP UDP Service Provider passed the loopback communication test.
info    Provider entry RSVP TCP Service Provider passed the loopback communication test.
info    Connectivity is valid for all Winsock service providers.
Wireless Diagnostic
Wireless - Service disabled
Wireless - User SSID
action  User input required: Specify network name or SSID
Wireless - First time setup
info    The Wireless Network name (SSID) to which the user would like to connect = RodSof Wifi.
Wireless - Radio off
info    Valid IP address detected: 192.168.0.10
Wireless - Out of range
Wireless - Hardware issue
Wireless - Novice user
Wireless - Ad-hoc network
Wireless - Less preferred
Wireless - 802.1x enabled
Wireless - Configuration mismatch
Wireless - Low SNR
Network Adapter Diagnostic
Network location detection
info    Using home Internet connection
Network adapter identification
info    Network connection: Name=Local Area Connection 2, Device=Realtek RTL8168C(P)/8111C(P) PCI-E Gigabit Ethernet NIC, MediaType=LAN, SubMediaType=LAN
info    Network connection: Name=Wireless USB, Device=NETGEAR WG111v2 54Mbps Wireless USB 2.0 Adapter, MediaType=LAN, SubMediaType=WIRELESS
info    Both Ethernet and Wireless connections available, prompting user for selection
action  User input required: Select network connection
info    Wireless connection selected
Network adapter status
info    Network connection status: Connected
HTTP, HTTPS, FTP Diagnostic
HTTP, HTTPS, FTP connectivity
info    FTP (Active): Successfully connected to ftp.microsoft.com.
warn    HTTP: Error 12007 connecting to www.microsoft.com: The server name or address could not be resolved
warn    HTTP: Error 12002 connecting to www.hotmail.com: The operation timed out
warn    HTTPS: Error 12002 connecting to www.passport.net: The operation timed out
warn    HTTPS: Error 12002 connecting to www.microsoft.com: The operation timed out
error   Could not make an HTTP connection.
error   Could not make an HTTPS connection.
```

Comment: is the gateway on the Wired & wireless connection the same ?

Comment: Try disabling any wired connections in the Network Connections list.

Comment: Tried doing a forced update of the firmware?

Comment: @boot13: I tried this with no joy - I thought maybe there were clashing but I disabled the hardware and no there are no other network adapters enabled.

Comment: Does item 13 on your list refer to two different laptops, or one laptop with two wireless interfaces enabled simultaneously?

Answer (score 1):

In these type of situations I usually delete of wireless profiles and then from the command line under the admin account I use the `netsh` function

```
netsh Int ip reset all 

netsh winsock reset
```

This will require a system restart.

Have a read of this article: [Resetting your network adapter in Windows XP](http://www.geeksinphoenix.com/blog/post/2010/11/21/Resetting-your-network-adapter-in-Windows-XP.aspx)

Answer (score 0):

> As soon as I plug in the ethernet cable it all works fine. Repairing the adapter sometimes helps but it will always stop working after a random time.

I'm basically clueless also. The only thing that comes to mind is that possibly you are having problems reaching/using the DNS servers. I realize that the fact that your laptop & iPhone work implies that this is **not** the problem. But I'm not sure what else to suggest.

I would suggest switching over to using either [Google Public DNS](http://code.google.com/speed/public-dns/) or the [Open DNS](http://www.opendns.com/) servers. They are free and supposedly provide some basic "bad site" filtering benefits so why not try switching and see what happens?

Some things that weren't clear to me from your question:

1. You mentioned you have updated **ALL** of your drivers. Does this include the firmware for your integrated ADSL router?

   (FWIW, I'm beginning to form a really bad opinion of these ISP provided integrated modem/router devices which I assume is what you have. My preference would be to use a separate ADSL modem coupled with one of the commonly used home routers. It gives you more options IMO. Oh, well.)
2. Have you used the PC via the wired ethernet connection for a long enough period of time to have a high degree of confidence that this problem does *not* also occur in that context? If the problem "goes away" immediately after establishing/repairing a connection, that might be what is also happening when you use a wired connection.
3. It is not clear from your question whether or not you can or can**not** use your local LAN when this problem occurs. I'm also not clear to what extent your ability to reach the Internet is compromised.

   You said you can ping Google via their IP address. Can you do this even when you cannot otherwise "reach" the Internet? Can you access your router's admin page when you cannot reach the Internet? (This should work if you can still connect using IP addresses).

Answer (score 0):

Have you got security on your wireless, if so try it without and see how long it lasts.

Other suggestions:

Get a website's IP address (By using http://locateip.co.uk, eg bbc.co.uk = 212.58.224.138), and note it down somewhere, when the internet connection dissapears on your PC enter the IP Address into a browser and see if the page will load. If it does then there's something wrong with the DNS settings on your computer (like it's set to an incorrect server).

Changing DNS server on your router won't help as your other devices are fine.

It is possible that your router is blocking the PCs MAC Address or IP Address. My router has this functionality, and I've used it before and forgotten about it and wondered why, it also has a delay from when the computer connects to the network to when it is blocked. I'd think it's unlikely this is the case though.

When the internet connection goes, does the network conenction as well? Eg can you access file shares on other computers?

Comment: Thanks for the response. I tried entering the IP address directly - it does the same thing so I do not think it is a DNS issue.

It's a brand new router/setup so there's no old settings, but I double checked and the IP address for the PC is being leased fine (ie. it is talking to the router initially) 

I set up a wifi network which works fine when internet is working, but also stops when this happens. I then cannot connect to the router over http either.

Answer (score 0):

"I can ping google.com and it replies (**sometimes with packet loss**)"

Try to ping other sites to see if a loss occurs. Google was out one day. I used to have pesky ADSL, and every time there was rain/moisture, it would have an intermittent connection. Also, if it's idle for a while, ADSL won't respond until pinged (woken up).

Try it manually from the command prompt

```
ipconfig /release
ipconfig /renew
```

A trace router might show you a bottleneck. From the command prompt:

```
tracert www.google.com    (or other site)
```