# Able to ping but does not get the data

Tags: internet, ip-address

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Wireless internet connection connects but internet does not work (no packets received). Wired does](https://superuser.com/questions/182069/wireless-internet-connection-connects-but-internet-does-not-work-no-packets-rec)

I am facing a problem in my client server program; when using wireless I can ping but not receive any data.

There is a source which receives a streaming request from client via server. This works fine when all the machines are connected through LAN cable but when I put all the computers in wi-fi network, all the machine are able to ping each other but when the client send the stream request to the server the ping request between server and client says `destination unreachable`.

It works all well until the client does not send the streaming request. What might be the issue?

**Edit**
So, simply put, when using wireless I can ping but do not receive any data. When wired I can ping and receive data.

Comment: So your issue is when using wireless you can ping but do not receive any data?

Comment: @DaveRook Ya sir

Comment: @DaveRook Its for win xp hope so same work for win 7